# Padding through CSS on HTML attributed text for textView is not working

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am rendering a textview with HTML content. I have taken some "div" tags and applied some CSS on them. I faced an issue while applying padding on "div" using a CSS class which is not reflecting on the div after rendering on the textview. I used the following method to convert HTML content string to an attributed string.

```
if let htmlData = htmlContent.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true) {
    do {
        return try NSMutableAttributedString(
                       data: htmlData,
                       options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                       documentAttributes: nil)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        printDebuggingMode("Couldn't translate \(htmlContent): \(error.localizedDescription) ")
    }
}
```

I want to achieve something like this as attached below in the image in textView.

[image]

```
.padding {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: html to `NSAttributedString` really only works for lightweight conversions. For a brief discussion of that see [here](http://ericasadun.com/2015/08/24/css-and-attributed-strings/). Have you tried using a `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`?

Comment: @beyowulf, actually I have requirement to show some html content section wise so I have taken textview inside tableviewCell. so there each section with section header has one raw inside it with textview where i have to render html content which has css also. I took textview because  1. uiTableViewAutomaticDimension make row hight adjustable as per textview content, 2. i have to provide text selection for highlight.

Comment: Okay. Well, `UITextView`, like `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` has no intrinsic content size, so I'm not sure how that's _more_ helpful with automatic dimension. And, text is selectable, but not editable, in web views as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `UITextView` does not support *padding* attributes inside HTML content. With that in mind you have two options here:

On one hand, use `UIWebView`, as suggested in replies. You'll have same functionality as in an `UITextView`, but you'll have to calculate the height of your text using something like this:

This method returns the height without considering insets of the `UITextView`, you'll need to add those later.

```
func heightForText(text: String?, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    //Get attributed text from string
    let attributedText = text?.toHtmlTextWithAttributes()

    if let attributedText = attributedText {
        let rect = attributedText.boundingRectWithSize(
            CGSizeMake(width, CGFloat.max),
            options: [.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, .UsesFontLeading],
            context: nil)
        return rect.height
    }

    //Return any default height
    return 100
}
```

Here is the `String` extension which transforms text into `NSAttributedString`.

```
extension String {
    public func toHtmlTextWithAttributes() -> NSAttributedString? {

        let encodedData = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        if let data = encodedData {

            let paragrahpStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragrahpStyle.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
            let attributes: [String: NSObject] = [
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragrahpStyle,
                NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
            ]

            return try! NSAttributedString(data: data, options: attributes, documentAttributes: nil)
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Also the use of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`  is not recommended, because in quite large lists it may lead to performance issues.

On the other hand, if you need to use `UITextView` by all means, you can parse the html, extract the title and the paragraph and display them in two separated `UITextView`. In that way you'll be able to adjust the insets of the second `UITextView` like this:

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Swift 5: `UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)`